# Remove all hyperlinks from a spreadsheet

Tags: libreoffice, gnumeric

When I copy/paste from a website into gnumeric (or LibreOffice Calc) from a website, I want to be able to quickly strip away all hyperlinks and leave just text.

How do I do this?

Solutions in either program will be accepted, although gnumeric is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Gnuneric: Menu "`Edit`" -> "`Clear...`" -> "`Formats and Hyperlinks`":

[image]

Another way is selecting the cells to edit, right-click and select "`Remove [n] Hyperlinks`".

Answer (score 30):

In LibreOffice Calc (Version: 4.1.3.2; Build ID: 410m0(Build:2):

- select the cells containing hyperlinks
- Click on *Format > Clear Direct Formatting* (or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)

That's all.

Comment: When typing in a username@hostname.com Calc automatically turns it into a link (including wonky formatting), when all I really wanted was just the text.

Comment: When clicking "Clear Direct Formatting" make sure you have the mouse pointer above the cell, not the actual link. It doesn't work for me if I right click the link.

Answer (score 2):

When you copy the info, and you're ready to paste, click on Edit --> Paste Special --> Unformattted text, and once the new window opens, review the info,choose your text import settings, and then click OK.  See images below.

The text example in the last image, are links from a website, and it got pasted as text, and not hyperlinks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this is only intermittently available - usually paste special is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

In LibreOffice Calc (Version: 4.3.7.2; Build ID: 4.3.7.2-2.el6_9.2):

1. Click Edit => Links...
2. Click 'Break Link' and 'Yes' on every line item
3. Click Close

Comment: I click edit, but "links" is grayed out

Answer (score 1):

In LibreOffice Calc,
Go to the menu Header on top-->from the dropdown selection of paste button select unformatted text and you're done!